# Riemann sum given partition and sample points

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the Riemann sum $R(f,p,c)$ for the function $f(x)=3x^2+2x$.

Partition $p={0,1,2.5,3.2,5}$  and sample points $c={0.5,2,3,4.5}$.

Am able to find a Riemann sum whereby partitions have been given. In this case, am wondering were the sample points are to be used in calculation.

Comment: Evaluate the function $f$ at the sample point, multiply by the length of the interval of the partition.  Add these up, one term for each interval in the partition.

Comment: Do you mean 5/5(f(0.5)+f(2)+f(3)+f(4)+f(5))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the partition $0,1,2.5,3.2,5$
and sample points  $0.5,2,3,4.5$, the Riemann sum is
$$
f(0.5) \;\cdot\big( 1-0\big)
+f(2)\;\cdot\big( 2.5-1\big)
+f(3)\;\cdot\big( 3.2-2.5\big)
+f(4.5)\;\cdot\big( 5-3.2\big)
$$

[Note: the edit of $4.5$ into $4,5$ was incorrect.  This partition has four intervals, so we need four sample points.]

Comment: I get it now. Appreciative